# how to use "testflight" for android app that are not published on playstore?

Tags: android, testing, remote-debugging, crash-reports, android-anr-dialog

I'm developing an android app for a specific client, and I want ***track*** the ***remote crashes*** and ***anr(app not responding) issues***.

How can I start using ***TestFlight***?

Also you can provide me some alternatives, but with proper documentation or links.

Thanks in advance.

Can anybody also tell me, how to implement testflight sdk correctly??

I have already downloaded the sdk, get the app token and integrated as mentioned in Jafar's answer, afterwards I upload apk on testflight, but on web it shows cross symbol under sdk column and says implement sdk.

Comment: I am using BugSense and found it very easy to use...www.bugsense.com

Comment: @AakashGoyal Does it requires any fee or charges ??

Comment: They have a free package that you can use

Answer (score 1):

Download the android version of test flight sdk from this link and add into the libs folder.

[Test flight sdk here](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/)

Firstly you have to add permission in the AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Than add the code in the applicaiton file in the oncreate method.

```
TestFlight.takeOff(this, YOUR_APP_TOKEN);
```

You can obtain app token by adding a new app.

Credentials require for adding new app is the app name and package name.

When a new application is created successfully than get the app-token and add this token id in your code.
As shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: where to use `TestFlight.land()` method ??

Comment: I have never used this method. As far as i know this method has no use in order to show whether your app contains test flight sdk or not.

Answer (score 0):

I use test flight to keep track of my beta testers.

You have to integrate TestFlight sdk into your app, it's pretty easy.

You have to register to TestFlight, create your app and you will get an app token.
With this app token you can initialize the tracker in your app, and it will keep track of crashes and many other things.
You will see the log in testflight website, in your application details page.

[Getting started with test flight sdk for android](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/android/doc/1.2/)

[Test Flight sdk](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/)

Comment: where to use land method(`TestFlight.land()`)

Comment: I've never used that method, never heard about it...I'm sorry...what it should do?